# Not able to configure SLO in Okta

Tags: okta, single-logout

I am trying to implement Single LogOut from my Service Provider using Okta.
I have the app configured in Okta. The SSO is working fine. Just that when I am logging out of the application it is not logging me out of Okta as a result if I re login it is just logging me with the same user name without taking me to the log in page.

I have configured the SLO settings as seen in the picture.[image: Picture1]

Also I am using the Url from the IDP Metadata in the SP.

And I have updated the same Signature Certificate as provided by Okta as seen in the picture:[image: Picture2]

Requirements:

1. When I log out, it should log me out of the current application as well as Okta.
2. When I re log in, It should ask for credentials.

I tried looking into https://help.okta.com/en-us/Content/Topics/Apps/Apps_Single_Logout.htm
But could not understand what the actual issue was.

Answer (score 0):

In the SP Issuer you have to put the metadata uri as mentioned in the okta guide for configuring SLO at [Get Started with Spring Boot and SAML](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/08/05/spring-boot-saml)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35817951)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).